# std::is_convertible for type_info

Tags: c++, types, casting, c++11, typecast-operator

In C++11 it is possible to determine if a variable of type A can be implicitly converted to type B by `using std::is_convertible<A, B>`.

This works well if you actually know the types A and B, but all I have is type_infos. So what I'm looking for is a function like this:

```
bool myIsConvertible(const type_info& from, const type_info& to);
```

Is it possible to implement something like that in C++? If so, how?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But the real question is, what would you do with such a function?

Comment: Also, why would you only have `type_info`s?

Comment: "This works well if you actually know the types A and B". Ok, but how come you don't know the types?

Comment: I think we need a zoom out: what is the problem that you were trying to solve that got you in this mess in the first place ?

Comment: If you don't know A and B but know they are convertible, you still can't do a conversion anyway, so why would you ask for that ?

Comment: There are perfectly good reasons why you need to do this. "Type erasure" happens if you need to store a collection of templated types, you have to store a base class reference and the derived type is lost. Not everything can be polymorphic, e.g. "get Value" can't be polymorphic if the value is of type T.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible in portable C++ to do what you want.

It *may* be possible to achieve a partial answer **if** you restrict yourself to a given platform.  For example those platforms that adhere to the [Itanium ABI](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/) will have an implementation of this function:

```
extern "C" 
void* __dynamic_cast(const void *sub,
                     const abi::__class_type_info *src,
                     const abi::__class_type_info *dst,
                     std::ptrdiff_t src2dst_offset);
```

In this ABI, `abi::__class_type_info` is a type derived from `std::type_info`, and *all* `std::type_info`s in the program have a dynamic type derived from `std::type_info` (`abi::__class_type_info` being just one example).

Using this ABI it is possible to build a tool that will navigate the inheritance hierarchy of any type (at run time), given its `std::type_info`.  And in doing so you could determine if two `std::type_info`s represent two types that could be `dynamic_cast` or even `static_cast` to each other.

Note that such a solution would not take into account converting among types using a converting constructor or conversion operator.  And even if that restriction is acceptable, I don't recommend this route.  This is not an easy project, and would be very error prone.  But this is probably how your C++ implementation implements `dynamic_cast`, so it is obviously not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this could be done in case you know the typeid of your variable , Which you can always know using the typeid operator in c++ .

```
  Derived* pd = new Derived;
  Base* pb = pd;
  cout << typeid( pb ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Base *"
  cout << typeid( *pb ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Derived"
  cout << typeid( pd ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Derived *"
```

Then you would have to create a `multimap` or with key as `typeid`(which you want to know if is convertible to ) and value as `convertible type ids` ( convertable type ) Where like if . Here in this case then you can access the map to search if a `key`  in your case `const type_info& from` has a `value` mapped to `const type_info& to` . If Yes then you can return bool as `true` or `false` . But in this case you need to make sure that you see all classes and there inheritance in the code properly . And on the basis decides if it will be a legal conversion and add on the map on that basis . But this would be a tedious process and I dont see any use of it .

Genrally c++ lets you know through `dynamic cast` if a type can be casted to other type or not properly. While `static_cast` will even cast incompitble types to one another and Improper use of which would lead to run-time error