# How to tell if a type is a subclass using type_info?

Tags: c++, rtti

I use C++ with RTTI. I have a `type_info` of a class. How can I tell whether another class is a subclass of the first one, if I only have the `type_info`?

```
#include <typeinfo>

class Foo             { public: virtual ~Foo() {} };
class Boo: public Foo { public: virtual ~Boo() {} };
class Bar             { public: virtual ~Bar() {} };

template<class T>
bool instanceOf(const type_info& info) {
  // ANSWER COMES HERE!!
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  const type_info& fooInfo = typeid(Foo);
  const type_info& barInfo = typeid(Bar);

  bool booIsFoo = instanceOf<Boo>(fooInfo); // should be true
  bool booIsBar = instanceOf<Boo>(barInfo); // should be false

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid `std::is_base_of`?

Comment: Do you have to use `type_info`?  Can't this be done by testing the result of a cast?

Comment: I want to store type_info, and test inheritance later. `std::is_base_of` and `dynamic_cast` need the type as template parameter, which I can't store for later use.

Comment: It seems tremendously simpler to check when you have the object and store the boolean :) Also you could keep a pointer to the object and defer the test otherwise.

Comment: @ThomasMoulard: Unfortunately the list of types I test against is determined runtime by user action. I could test all objects against all types, but it seems to be an overkill.

Comment: This sounds like asking about a problem with your perceived solution Y to some undisclosed problem X. Rather ask about X. The Y solution is ungood.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: thanks, but I really asked what I wanted an answer for. I explained why because I was asked about it, not because that's my real question.

Comment: So, your end goal isn't to solving a practical problem, but rather learning about the quirks of some specific language features?  Stack overflow works best if you (A) have a practical problem, and (B) show what you tried, then (C) point out where it failed.  This really, really looks like you had a practical problem, thought up a solution but it didn't work because you could not solve this sub-problem.  You then posted this sub-problem, asking how to solve it.  Quite probably your overall problem has a simple solution, but your narrow sub-problem is unrelated to the overall one.  This is X/Y.

Comment: @Yakk: my goal with this question was to learn about the quirks of some specific language feature. I didn't know that it won't work out. But I had to ask this question so that I'll learn that I need to take a step back, and ask a different question instead.

Comment: this answer can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508092/5197544

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have two typeinfo A and B. There is no general way to determine if A is a subclass of B.

You may:

1. store this information by yourself (static structure filled at runtime?)
2. make educated guesses using the type name (i.e. parsing the type info string and name the types accordingly).

Previous answers. They require you to instantiate the type somehow:

`type_info` is not the right tool for this, you should `dynamic_cast` if you absolutely want to check at runtime:

```
template<class Base, typename Derived>
bool instanceOf(const Derived& object) {
  return !dynamic_cast<Base*>(object);
}
```

You can also check at compile time using `std::is_base_of` as Steephen mentioned (C++11 needed).

```
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
static constexpr bool instanceOf() {
    return std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>()
}
```

Another solution:

```
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
bool instanceOf(const Derived& object) {
  try {
      throw object;
  } catch (const Base&) {
      return true;
  } catch (...) {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `return ! (dynamic_cast<T*>(object))`

Comment: Thanks, but these solutions require that I specify the superclass as a template parameter, so it's available compile-time. However I want to test inheritance against a type that I determine (and store) runtime. That's why I need type_info.

Comment: A typeinfo is merely a string, it does not hold any relationship information per-se so you will need to rely on some other additional mechanism. (edit: fixed comment)

Comment: Thanks, this explains why it's not really possible this way. :( I sort of hoped it contained more info than just a simple string.

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. It is not possible directly but of course if you store manually the relation between types you should be able to achieve what you want somehow...

Comment: I don't see how the dynamic_cast example is supposed to work.
Derived can most likely not be cast into Base*.
It should probably be:

    return !dynamic_cast<Base*>(&object);